# Complexity for a limited for loop iterations

Tags: java

### I have a quick question about Complexity. I have this code in Java:

`pairs` is a `HashMap` that contains an `Integer` as a key, and it's frequency in a `Collection<Integer>` as a value. So :

```
pairs = new Hashmap<Integer number, Integer numberFrequency>()
```

Then I want to find the matching Pairs `(a,b)` that verify `a + b == targetSum`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.getCapacity(); i++) { // Complexity : O(n)
    if (pairs.containsKey(targetSum - i) && targetSum - i == i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < pairs.get(targetSum - i); j++) {
            collection.add(new MatchingPair(targetSum - i, i));
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the complexity of the first For loop is O(n), but the second for Loop it only loops a small amount of times, which is the frequency of the number-1, do we still count it as O(n) so this whole portion of code will be O(n^2) ? If it is does  someone have any alternative to just make it O(n) ?

Answer (score 1):

Its O(n) if 'pairs.getCapacity()' or 'pairs.get(targetSum - i)' is a constant you know before hand. Else, two loops, one nested in the other, is generally O(n^2).

Comment: Yes pairs.getcapacity() is a constant, which is the map's capacity, a pairs.get(targetSum- i) is an integer that represents the frequence of a number, that number is targetSum -i... Since we don't know it i guess it is O(n^2), even though the frequence may be really small (from 0 to 10 max prob, if we look at the collection of integers we have to create pairs that sum up to targetSum)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider that for the wors case your complexity is O(n2)